# Regexp in ruby - can I use parenthesis without grouping?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a regexp of the form:

```
/(something complex and boring)?(something complex and interesting)/
```

I'm interested in the contents of the second parenthesis; the first ones are there only to ensure a correct match (since the boring part might or might not be present but if it is, I'll match it by accident with the regexp for the interesting part).

So I can access the second match using $2. However, for uniformity with other regexps I'm using I want that somehow $1 will contain the contents of the second parethesis. Is it possible?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick and enlightening answer!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use a non-capturing group:

```
r = /(?:ab)?(cd)/
```

Answer (score 9):

This is a non-ruby regexp feature. Use `/(?:something complex and boring)?(something complex and interesting)/` (note the `?:`) to achieve this.

By the way, in Ruby 1.9, you can do `/(something complex and boring)?(?<interesting>something complex and interesting)/` and access the group with `$~[:interesting]` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yup, use the `?:` syntax:

```
/(?:something complex and boring)?(something complex and interesting)/
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not  a ruby developer however I know other regex flavors. So I bet you can use a **non capturing group**

```
/(?:something complex and boring)?(something complex and interesting)/
```

There is only one capturing group, hence $1

HTH

Answer (score -4):

Not really, no. But you can use a named group for uniformity, like this:

```
/(?<group1>something complex and boring)?(?<group2>something complex and interesting)/
```

You can change the names (the text in the angle brackets) for the uniformity that you want to achieve. You can then access the groups like this:

```
string.match(/(?<group1>something complex and boring)?(?<group2>something complex and interesting)/) do |m|
    # Do something with the match, m['group'] can be used to access the group
end
```